# qtip throwing an error in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, iis-7.5, qtip2

I am having trouble getting a qTip (qTip2) to display in Internet Explorer 9 to a page served up by my local IIS in Windows 8.

I have the following page saved to 1.htm in my default IIS website (DefaultAppPool .NET4.0 Integrated managed pipeline)

```
http://localhost/1.htm
```

...and a remote website (http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/qtip/1.htm).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/qtip/jquery.qtip.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tooltip">Here is a tooltip</div>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/qtip/jquery.qtip.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tooltip').each(function () {
                $(this).qtip({
                    content: 'tooltip',
                    hide: {
                        fixed: true,
                        delay: 200
                    },
                    position: {
                        my: 'top left',
                        at: 'bottom center',
                        target: $(this)
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. If I navigate to http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/qtip/1.htm with **Chrome** (latest), the tooltip works fine.
2. If I navigate to http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/qtip/1.htm with **IE9**, the tooltip works fine.
3. If I navigate to http://imagehost.bigwavesoftware.net/qtip/1.htm with **IE8**, the tooltip works fine.
4. If I open 1.htm directly from disk in **IE9**, the tooltip works fine.
5. If I navigate to `http://localhost/1.htm` with **IE9**, the tooltip throws an error in the jQuery library.

There is something about serving this page up in local IIS that is making IE9 choke on it.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Btw, the qtip libraries in the below example are hosted on my personal server and are the latest v2.0.1-31- versions.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a cross-domain restriction - when running under IIS, you're asking the site on `localhost:yourportnumber` to fetch data from `bigwavesofsoftware.net`, which is normally not allowed. Directly loading the file doesn't trigger that since it's not seen as a request from another domain - it's a direct request from the source file.

Comment: Ok, I think CDN's are loaded from other URLs, so is that the same thing?

Comment: @John Not entirely - requesting a resource from a CDN via a normal HTTP request (perhaps via the `href` value of a `<link />` tag, and so on) is fine, and most sites will allow it. Requesting a resource via a JavaScript call is treated differently - most browsers won't do so without special instructions; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy